# How do you create and modify popover in Bootstrap 5 using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover, bootstrap-5

Does someone know how I can create and add data to bootstrap 5 popover via javascript/jquery?

With bootstrap 3 I was able to do this:

```
$('#element').popover({ placement : 'left', trigger : 'focus', html: true });
let content_template = `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`;
$('#element').data('bs.popover').options.content = content_template;
```

But I can't figure out how I can do the same with bootstrap 5. The documentation doesn't mention anything about this. Does anyone know how popovers are managed in BS5?

Comment: You should be seeking to eliminate jQuery from a Bootstrap 5 project (unless you have to support comically old browsers). It's had its day and is widely considered obsolete in modern apps.

Comment: React is fine if you're developing using Node.js, but not everyone does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get instance of popover and then use `popover_instance._config.content ="some message"` to set new content inside your popover .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle]'), {
  placement: 'left',
  trigger: 'focus',
  html: true
})
//get instance
var popover_instance = bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle]'))
let content_template = `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`;
popover_instance._config.content = content_template;//set content
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. Apparently it doesn't support <table></table> inside popover anymore? When I try to add the following content I just get a blank popover with no content:

let content_template = `<table><tr><th>Testing</th></tr><tr><td>Something</td></tr></table>`;

Comment: That's a different question that you shouldn't be raising here.

Comment: Well just in case somebody faces the same problem, you need to set sanitize: false when you create the popover.

Answer (score 3):

Use vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery. The popover instance is returned from instantiation. You can then use this to modify the content...

```
const bsPopover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle]'), {
  placement: 'left',
  trigger: 'focus',
  html: true
})

bsPopover._config.content = `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`;
bsPopover.setContent();
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/L9CMTcrJkU)

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on updating popover content multiple times you also need to call `setContent()` on popover instance. Like this

```
popoverInstance._config.content = "Hello world";
popoverInstance.setContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get instance of popover and use `setContent` method (see the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/#methods)

The only argument of the `setContent` method is an object with following format

```
const element = document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle]');
const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(element);
popover.setContent({
    '.popover-header': 'My Header',
    '.popover-body': '<b>my content</b>'
});
```

Comment: For reasons beyond my comprehension, this seems to result in an error ''querySelector' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.'  Setting _config.content directly, then calling setContent(), without arguments, was the only way I could manage to update the popover.

Comment: Have you set any Popover options such as template?

Comment: No, I'm just using the default template.

Comment: const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#example');

 try using this then setContent the same way